# CodeIgniter: create a html template for different languages

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates, translation

I have a little issue with that subject.

Imagine, I need to create a template with some variables:

```
<div class="main_text">
    We would like to tell you that ...blah-blah...
    <?php $username ?>
    and after that we want to blah blah... 
    <?php $first_variable ?>
    and
    <?php $second_variable ?> etc.
<div>
```

I can see two ways for making this working with different languages:

1. Create a template for each language. It is faster, but makes more
   code.
2. Create language constants in a codeigniter way, for each part of string, like this:

   ```
   $lang['WE_WOULD_LIKE'] = 'We would like to tell you that ...blah-blah...';
   $lang['AND_AFTER_THAT'] = 'and after that we want to blah blah...';
   ```

And then populate it while parsing the template. This way is also not the best, too much small constants.

Maybe somebody knows a better way? Please show me the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codeigniter actually has a built in [**language class**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/language.html).

> Language files are typically stored in your system/language directory.
>   Alternately you can create a folder called language inside your
>   application folder and store them there. CodeIgniter will look first
>   in your application/language directory. If the directory does not
>   exist or the specified language is not located there CI will instead
>   look in your global system/language folder.

Usage would be like the following once the desired language is set:

```
$this->lang->line('language_key');
```

**Update:** To pass variable's to the language variables you can use PHP's [**sprintf**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php):

```
$lang['WE_WOULD_LIKE'] = "We would like to tell you that %1$s and %2$s";
```

And then to get that variable:

```
$message = sprintf($this->lang->line('WE_WOULD_LIKE'), $first, $second);
```

Comment: ok, language files instead of variables, but this is close to second decision. I can't put variables inside the language constant strings.

Comment: @Bandydan I updated my answer to show how you can use variables.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using constants, you should use the language array, which was meant for this purpose. Look at: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/language.html

Once you create your language files, you load them in your controller, as such:

```
$this->lang->load('welcome_page', $lang_from_session_or_db);
```

`$lang_from_session_or_db` should vary based on the user's language, so you would store this in a session variable, or in the database, depending on your project.

You can then access those vars using:

```
$this->lang->line('language_key');
```

Because where you place your variables will vary based on language, you may want to look into the printf family of functions.

Comment: yes, I got that, language constants instead of global, but it is still the second way I mentioned.

Comment: These are not constants, please do not mistake the two. Instead of having many small strings, you can use a longer string and `sprintf` your data.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use define() since that creates global variables and you probably don't want to pollute the global namespace.

Code Igniter provides a class for helping with this.
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/language.html

This is preferable since you will be able to load the language class only where you need it, and you won't have global variables all over the place.

Comment: Even if it vould be not defined global constants, question is, is there a third way behind language files and different templates?